# Amplify Fetching is too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

- aws-cli/2.1.21 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/19.6.0
- amplify CLI 4.41.2
- macOS 10.15.6

### question:

Amplify fetching process is too long.

please help to me..

### I was try below.

1. amplify init
2. amplify add api -> REST API
3. amplify push

Fetching started when last command.

console is

'Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud. '

I waited a hour.

but process is not complete.

Please tell me I have to confirm where.

### other

Previously, I manually deleted the amplify related resource.

(e.g. cloudformation, s3,and more)

This may have been bad.

Answer (score 0):

What is strange about you situation is that you are pushing information, but I'm not certain that you mentioned you had a stable cloud version. Meaning this, if there was an unstable version on the cloud and a heavily modified local version it could cause issue (such is what i have seen when working on it). My advice would be to ensure you have a cleanly design cloud version with amplify studio https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/ could help with general commands though "Amplify --help" is another option.

Aside from that, "Amplify pull" would overwrite your local system, but assuming it is a clean version you could then push it. I have actually save files off to my desktop and then copied them back in and that has worked for me. Fundamentally the issue is that it is a cloud system you are relying on. Major modifications will often be ignored or overwritten. **Wish I could help more.**